# Chrome not updating scripts and rss because of cookies or something?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome, rss

im having trouble developing using chrome as my preview browser, it doesnt seem to update changes regularly- im assuming its some sort of cookie issue because it seems to update properly when using incognito for previewing. Unfortunately, this still doesnt reload the rss page i am trying to load for a long time(it takes about half an hour for it to update the rss feed)

im using chrome because i prefer the developer tools in that browser

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not sure about **cookies**, but it could be a **caching** issue. Try using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> (Mac) to force the page to reload from the server.

You can also clear the contents of Chrome's cache from *Preferences → Under the Hood → Clear Browsing Data...* or using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd> (Mac).

(See also [Chrome Keyboard Shortcuts](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=25799&topic=28650).)

Comment: hmm that seems to fix my scripting issue, but its still having trouble updating the rss feed

Comment: I don't understand what the RSS feed problem is.

Comment: i have some javascript that reads rss data. when i update content on the rss, it takes like half an hour for the application to realize the rss has been updated. if you go to the path of the rss it shows the updated information, but the application refuses to load new data for a long time

Comment: @user667122:  The user has a browser preference that tells his RSS feed how often to update (every 30 minutes by default in Safari).  AFAIK, you cannot over-ride that but you can change it for your own browser, although 30 minutes is the smallest interval in Safari.  (Safari & Chrome are both Webkit)

Answer (score 0):

Can't be cookies... only you, as the page developer, can write the script that creates or reads a cookie. Cookies don't just pop up out of nowhere and I don't know how a cookie could prevent a page from updating/refreshing. Sounds like a cache issue as already answered by @Matt Ball.

As far as the RSS feed, the end user tells the browser (in preferences) how often to update his feed. (**every 30 minutes** is the default and also the smallest interval in Safari).  Safari, like Chrome, is a Webkit browser.

Comment: thanks, i guess once im finished it wont be much of an issue, but it sure makes development a pain

Comment: @user667122:  Yeah, I'm unaware of any quick/easy way to force the RSS feed to update on demand or at least more often.  I thought dumping the cache files would have done it.